# How to simulate string + string via expression?

Tags: c#, expression

How can I simulate string + string expression via c# expression. The Expression.Add method does not work.

string + string  expression like

"111" + "222" = "111222"

thanks

Comment: just `Console.WriteLine("000"+"111");`

Comment: LINQPad is your friend. If you decompile something like `var a = "1111"; var b = "222"; var c = a + b;`, you'll see this ends up as a call to `String.Concat`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert is there a way to use LinqPad to generate code like in canton7 answer? I can find only IL code

Comment: @AleksAndreev SharpLab is good at showing the underling C#, but in this case it will show `+`. You'll need to go down to the IL to see what's happening (you can see `call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string, string)`): https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANALiAlgGxgExAagD4AEAMABLgIwDcAsAFC4DMxATIQMKEDe1hXx9pRAsgAo+hAIYxiJIsACU7Tt0W4A7GMKZCwSlUUBfarqA==

Comment: @AleksAndreev: not that I know of. LINQPad can dump expression trees (`(from _ in (new[] {""}).AsQueryable() let a = "111" let b = "222" select a + b).Expression`) but this will print the *actual* expression (which really is `.Add`), so no good there. Then again, I don't mind reading IL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call into `string.Concat` (the C# compiler turns string concatenation into calls to `string.Concat` under the hood).

```
var concatMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });    

var first = Expression.Constant("a");
var second = Expression.Constant("b");
var concat = Expression.Call(concatMethod, first, second);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(concat).Compile();
Console.WriteLine(lambda()); // "ab"
```

Actually, if you write

```
Expression<Func<string, string string>> x = (a, b) => a + b;
```

and inspect it in the debugger, you'll see that it generates a `BinaryExpression` (with a `Method` of `string.Concat(string, string)`), not a `MethodCallExpression`. Therefore the compiler actually uses @kalimag's answer, and not mine. Both will work, however.

Answer (score 2):

`Expression.Add` has an overload that takes a `MethodInfo`, which can be any `static` method that is compatible with the given parameter types:

```
var concatMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(String.Concat), new [] { typeof(string), typeof(string)});
var expr = Expression.Add(Expression.Constant("a"), Expression.Constant("b"), concatMethod);
```

In practice this is similar to `Expression.Call`, but it produces a different expression tree and is displayed differently in the debugger.