# How to assign a binary operator to a delegate

Tags: c#

How would I assign an operator to a delegate?

```cs
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
Func<int, int, int> operation = /* int.operator+ or int.operator- */;
int result = operation(a, b);
```

I know of three ways to do so:

```cs
Func<int, int, int> operation = (a, b) => a + b;
```

This one wraps into an additional function call.

```
Func<C, C, C> operation = (Func<C, C, C>)typeof(C).GetMethod("op_Addition").CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<C, C, C>));
```

This one is hideous and doesn't work with primitives.

```cs
Expression<Func<C, C, C>> expression = (c, c2) => c + c2;
BinaryExpression binaryExpression = (BinaryExpression)expression.Body;
MethodInfo binaryExpressionMethod = binaryExpression.Method;
Func<C, C, C> operation = (Func<C, C, C>)binaryExpressionMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<C, C, C>));
```

This one is even more hideous and also doesn't work with primitives.

Is there an elegant way?

Comment: I am curious to know the answer to this too, but as per what I understand, since most operators are overloaded for different types (including primitive types), I doubt you will have direct access to it for creating a delegate. The closest would be your first clean attempt where there is a wrapper function

Comment: The first one is very *elegant*. Or what would be your definition of elegance?

Comment: Well, it's not a delegate for an operator. It's a delegate for a wrapper function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `.Compile` method of lambda expression:

```
Func<int, int, int> result;

var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "a");
var b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "b");
var body = Expression.Add(a, b);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int, int>>(body, a, b);
```

Now your `lambda` is `a + b` and ready for compile:

```
result = lambda.Compile();
Console.WriteLine(result(5, 2)); // print 7
```

Comment: OK cool, this works for primittives, unfortunately, it's still hideous lol

Comment: It doesn't work for strings, off the top of my head? You'll need to pass `string.Concat` as a final parameter to `Expression.Add`.

Comment: @canton7 yes I remember [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55182935/4685428) about string concatenation. But OP asked about binary operations on primitives (at least I understood question in this way)

Comment: Sure, I don't think there's anything wrong with your answer. I couldn't work out from the question what types he wanted to support. "Doesn't work with primitives" implies that he has tested them with non-primitives, which implies that perhaps he needs both? I don't know. I just wanted to mention in the comments, in case he or someone else used your (perfectly fine) answer, and then came a cropper with the `string` edge-case.

Comment: Well, the question was about any operators. It's easy to reference any other method group (`Func<int, int> f = SomeMethod;`), but it's only possible to reference operators by doing convoluted operations in runtime or by referencing an anonymous wrapper function.